# Matlab GUI button reaction

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am just trying to program a reaction test with a MATLAB GUI.

I've got one button which, after every click, appears at a random place and afterwards the needed time for the next click is shown.

Now I want that this button dissapears after clicking on it 10 times.

How can I program, that after the 10th click it just executes "close all;"?

Comment: Your main problem is that you need to keep a counter somewhere, yet your GUI callback functions don't have any persistent variables. Ask yourself: Where can you keep a 'counter' variable, in a place you can access between calls of your GUI callback function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code which does what you want.

As @Li-aung mentioned, I added a counter which keeps track of the number of times the pushbutton was pushed. The counter is stored in the handles structure of the figure; however you could make it a global variable for simplicity.

Here is the code with comments:

```
function RandomButton(~)


hFig = figure('Position',[100 100 200 200],'Visible','off');

handles.CounterText = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 150 60 30],'String','Counter')
handles.DisplayCounterText = uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[50 100 60 30],'String','0')

handles.Button = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton','position',[50 50 60 30],'String','Push here','Callback',@(s,e) Push);

handles.PushCounter = 0; %// Initialize counter

movegui(gcf,'center')
set(hFig,'Visible','on')

guidata(hFig,handles)

    function Push

        handles = guidata(hFig);

        handles.PushCounter = handles.PushCounter +1;

        set(handles.DisplayCounterText,'String',num2str(handles.PushCounter));

        if handles.PushCounter < 10 %// Assign condition to stop.

        set(hFig,'Visible','off');
        set(hFig,'Position',[1000*rand(1) 1000*rand(1) 200 200]); %// Assign random position 

        set(hFig,'Visible','on');

        guidata(hFig,handles) %// Update handles structure. Important!

        else

            close all
        end

    end
end
```

Here is a screenshot of the GUI:

[image]

Hope that helps get you started!

Comment: so @freaky did you try my suggestion?